# mysql - build code based on a diagram

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to construct a database, but I'm fairly clueless about MySql. The following is what I'm aiming at achieving:
http://snag.gy/eryLf.jpg

Here's what I coded so far (tables are created in left to right order as seen in the picture)

```
    CREATE TABLE person (
  id INT(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  fname VARCHAR(64),
  lname VARCHAR(64)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE bookauthor (
  book_id INT(11),
  author_id INT(11),
  FOREIGN KEY (author_id) REFERENCES person (id) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (book_id) REFERENCES book (id) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE bookpublisher (
  book_id INT(11),
  publisher_id INT(11),
  FOREIGN KEY (book_id) REFERENCES book (id) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (publisher_id) REFERENCES publisher(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE publisher (
  id INT(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(64)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE bookillustrator (
  book_id INT(11),
  illustrator_id INT(11),
  FOREIGN KEY (book_id) REFERENCES book(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (illustrator_id) REFERENCES person(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE book (
  id INT(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  title VARCHAR(256),
  type_id INT(11),
  publication_date DATE,
  value DECIMAL(10,2),
  price DECIMAL(10,2),
  notes TEXT,
  signed TINYINT(1),
  grade_id INT(10),
  bagged TINYINT(1)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE booktag (
  book_id INT(11),
  tag_id INT(11),
  FOREIGN KEY (book_id) REFERENCES book(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY(tag_id) REFERENCES tag(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE tag (
  id INT(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  value VARCHAR(64)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE type (
  id INT(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(64)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE grade (
  id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(256)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Also what kind of relationship is displayed in book to type, and book to grade?

Comment: I only see one question here, and that's the relationships of the tables. Book -> Type is 'type_id' in table 'book' = 'id' in table 'type'. Book -> Grade is 'grade_id' in table 'book' = 'id' in table 'grade'.

Comment: the code is my starting point, I'm fairly confident some parts in it are wrong and some things are not even coded - that would be question 1. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `book->type` and `book->grade` relationships are 1:n where `type` and `grade` are optional. This is easily created with MySQL Workbench.

This should do it:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `type`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `type` (
  `id` INT(10) NOT NULL ,
  `name` VARCHAR(256) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `grade`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `grade` (
  `id` INT(10) NOT NULL ,
  `name` VARCHAR(256) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `book`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `book` (
  `id` INT(10) NOT NULL ,
  `title` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL ,
  `type_id` INT(10) NULL ,
  `publication_date` DATE NULL ,
  `value` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL ,
  `price` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL ,
  `notes` TEXT NULL ,
  `signed` TINYINT(1) NULL ,
  `grade_id` INT(10) NULL ,
  `bagged` TINYINT(1) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  INDEX `fk_book_grade` (`grade_id` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_book_type1` (`type_id` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_book_grade`
    FOREIGN KEY (`grade_id` )
    REFERENCES `grade` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_book_type1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`type_id` )
    REFERENCES `type` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `tag`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tag` (
  `id` INT(10) NOT NULL ,
  `value` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `booktag`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `booktag` (
  `book_id` INT(10) NOT NULL ,
  `tag_id` INT(10) NOT NULL ,
  INDEX `fk_booktag_book1` (`book_id` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_booktag_tag1` (`tag_id` ASC) ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`book_id`, `tag_id`) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_booktag_book1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`book_id` )
    REFERENCES `book` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_booktag_tag1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`tag_id` )
    REFERENCES `tag` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `person`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `person` (
  `id` INT(10) NOT NULL ,
  `fname` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL ,
  `lname` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `bookillustrator`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bookillustrator` (
  `book_id` INT(10) NOT NULL ,
  `person_id` INT(10) NOT NULL ,
  INDEX `fk_bookillustrator_person1` (`person_id` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_bookillustrator_book1` (`book_id` ASC) ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`book_id`, `person_id`) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_bookillustrator_person1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`person_id` )
    REFERENCES `person` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_bookillustrator_book1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`book_id` )
    REFERENCES `book` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `bookauthor`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bookauthor` (
  `book_id` INT(10) NOT NULL ,
  `person_id` INT(10) NOT NULL ,
  INDEX `fk_bookauthor_person1` (`person_id` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_bookauthor_book1` (`book_id` ASC) ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`book_id`, `person_id`) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_bookauthor_person1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`person_id` )
    REFERENCES `person` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_bookauthor_book1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`book_id` )
    REFERENCES `book` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `publisher`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `publisher` (
  `id` INT(10) NOT NULL ,
  `name` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `bookpublisher`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bookpublisher` (
  `book_id` INT(10) NOT NULL ,
  `publisher_id` INT(10) NOT NULL ,
  INDEX `fk_bookpublisher_book1` (`book_id` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_bookpublisher_publisher1` (`publisher_id` ASC) ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`book_id`, `publisher_id`) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_bookpublisher_book1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`book_id` )
    REFERENCES `book` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_bookpublisher_publisher1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`publisher_id` )
    REFERENCES `publisher` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3eef2)

Comment: Thank you. What does contraint do? Is it basically keeping ids in sync(ie: adding a new book will also create records to related tables by FK) ?

Comment: @user1937588 The job of the constraint is to maintain data and relational integrity. Adding a new book **won't** create records in related tables. The constraints can, if defined, restrict/cascade `UPDATE` or `DELETE` actions. [The manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) is a good source on how this works.